# Pyspark pyarrow pandas_udf - GROUPED_MAP return dataframe with None NaN for IntegerType, TimestampType

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow

Best

At this moment I'm experimenting with pyspark **pandas_udf**, but unfortunately I encounter some issues when I return a DataFrame with: NA, None or NaNs in it. If I'm using a FloatType then the result is okey but as soon as I'm using a IntegerType, TimestampType etc... I receive an error & it doesn't work any more.

Here are some examples of what works & what doesn't work:

`What does work?`
Example 1)

```
custom_schema = StructType([
                        StructField('User',StringType(),True),
                        StructField('Sport',StringType(),True),
                        StructField('Age',IntegerType(),True),
                        StructField('Age_lag',FloatType(),True),
                        ])

# the schema is what it needs as an output format
@pandas_udf(custom_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def my_custom_function(pdf):
    # Input/output are both a pandas.DataFrame

    #return a totalaly different DataFrame
    dt = pd.DataFrame({'User': ['Alice', 'Bob'], 'Sport': ['Football', 'Basketball'], 'Age': [27, 34]})
    dt['Age_lag'] = dt['Age'].shift(1)

    return dt

df.groupby('id').apply(my_custom_function).toPandas()
```

Result:

```
    User    Sport   Age     Age_lag
0   Alice   Football    27  NaN
1   Bob     Basketball  34  27.0
2   Alice   Football    27  NaN
3   Bob     Basketball  34  27.0
```

Example 2)

If we change the **Type** of *Age_lag* into *IntegerType()* & fill the Na's by -1 then we still have a valid result (no NaNs)

```
custom_schema = StructType([
                        StructField('User',StringType(),True),
                        StructField('Sport',StringType(),True),
                        StructField('Age',IntegerType(),True),
                        StructField('Age_lag',IntegerType(),True),
                        ])

# the schema is what it needs as an output format
@pandas_udf(custom_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def my_custom_function(pdf):
    # Input/output are both a pandas.DataFrame

    #return a totalaly different DataFrame
    dt = pd.DataFrame({'User': ['Alice', 'Bob'], 'Sport': ['Football', 'Basketball'], 'Age': [27, 34]})
    dt['Age_lag'] = dt['Age'].shift(1).fillna(-1)

    return dt

df.groupby('id').apply(my_custom_function).toPandas()
```

Result:

```
    User    Sport   Age     Age_lag
0   Alice   Football    27  -1
1   Bob     Basketball  34  27
2   Alice   Football    27  -1
3   Bob     Basketball  34  27
```

What does not work?

Example 3)

**If** we leave out the **.fillna(-1)** then we receive the next error

```
custom_schema = StructType([
                        StructField('User',StringType(),True),
                        StructField('Sport',StringType(),True),
                        StructField('Age',IntegerType(),True),
                        StructField('Age_lag',IntegerType(),True),
                        ])

# the schema is what it needs as an output format
@pandas_udf(custom_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def my_custom_function(pdf):
    # Input/output are both a pandas.DataFrame

    #return a totalaly different DataFrame
    dt = pd.DataFrame({'User': ['Alice', 'Bob'], 'Sport': ['Football', 'Basketball'], 'Age': [27, 34]})
    dt['Age_lag'] = dt['Age'].shift(1)

    return dt

df.groupby('id').apply(my_custom_function).toPandas()
```

Result: **pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Floating point value truncated**

Example 4)

Last but not least, if we just send a static dataframe back where age_lag contains a **None**, then it doesn't work either.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,NullType, StructField,FloatType, LongType, DoubleType, StringType, IntegerType
# true means,  accepts nulls
custom_schema = StructType([
                        StructField('User',StringType(),True),
                        StructField('Sport',StringType(),True),
                        StructField('Age',IntegerType(),True),
                        StructField('Age_lag',IntegerType(),True),
                        ])

# the schema is what it needs as an output format
@pandas_udf(custom_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def my_custom_function(pdf):
    # Input/output are both a pandas.DataFrame

    #return a totalaly different DataFrame
    dt = pd.DataFrame({'User': ['Alice', 'Bob'], 
                      'Sport': ['Football', 'Basketball'], 
                        'Age': [27, 34], 
                    'Age_lag': [27, None]})


    return dt

df.groupby('id').apply(my_custom_function).toPandas()
```

**Questions**:

- How do you deal with this?
- Is it a poor design ?

  - (because I can imagine 1000 cases where I do want to return NaNs and Nones)
- Do we really have to fill in all the missing values? and replace them back afterwards? or work with floats instead if integers?  etc?
- will this be solved in the near future? (because pandas_udf s are quite new)

Comment: That's an interesting question, but I believe it would be a better fit on Apache Spark or Arrow developers list. If the behavior is intended, more specific error message could be desired and limitations documented. If not it should be documented as a bug. Finally only devs can speak about current and future work. As of missing values, Pandas [inherited](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) all the problems from NumPy and their approach is not fully exchangeable with Spark.